# I am confused on how to replace a sentence with 're.sub' for this particular problem

Tags: python, regex

I have trouble with changing this particular string with re.sub:

```
string = "
Name: Carolyn\r\n
Age : 20\r\n
Hobby: skiing, diving\r\n"
```

Is there a way to easily replace for example from `Hobby: skiing, diving\r\n` to `Hobby: swimming, reading\r\n`?

Comment: Why do need `re.sub` for that? Just call `string.replace`.

Comment: `string.replace("skiing, diving", "swimming, reading")`

Comment: @Wilbert What't the intent of the replacement? Are you trying to just overwrite `'skiing, diving'`, or are you trying to find the line containing `'Hobby:'` to change the value?

Comment: yeah sorry for the unclear question, I want to replace anything with "Hobby:", not just "skiing, diving".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to match anything after `Hobby` not just `skiing` and `diving` specifically. One option is to match the whole line, capture `Hobby:` in a capture group, and replace the line with the capture plus replacement text. You can use `re.M` to change to multiline mode allowing you to match the line ending rather than the string ending.

```
import re

string = '''
Name: Carolyn
Age : 20
Hobby: skiing, diving
'''

print(re.sub(r'(Hobby: ).*$', r'\1swimming, reading', string, flags=re.M))
```

**result**

```
Name: Carolyn
Age : 20
Hobby: swimming, reading
```